# C++ what is this little used constructor syntax?

Tags: c++, syntax, constructor

EDIT: I don't *think* this a duplicate of [this other question](http://I'm%20not%20sure%20this%20a%20duplicate%20of%20this%20other%20question,), because the other question simply transposes `()` for `{}` in the constructors. Whereas I note different behavior when a constructor is defined in a `struct`, but not in a `class`. (And, as pointed out in the comments, this is about using constructors not writing them.) But I've been wrong before.

I came across this strange (to me) syntax for a constructor while tutoring:

```
Foo obj {i, j};
```

At first I thought it wouldn't work, and told the student to rewrite it – however they were adamant it worked, and informed me they pulled the example from cplusplus.com, [to which I've not been able to find a reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/), so I tried it anyway... And it worked. So I experimented with it.

I also researched a bit on my own, and found no reference to that kind of [constructor syntax](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) on cplusplus.com. (Maybe it has a specific name?)

Here's what I did to experiment with it.

```
struct Note { //A musical note.
    std::string name;
    double freq;
    //Note(std::string s, double f): name(s), freq(f){}
    //Uncomment the constructor in order to use normal constructor syntax.
};

class Journal {
public:
    std::string title;
    std::string message;
    int idNum;
};

int main() {
    Note a { "A", 440.0}; //Works with or without a constructor.
    //Note a("A",440.0); //Works ***only*** with a defined constructor.

    //Journal journal("hello, world", "just me, a class", 002); //Works regardless of constructor definition.
    Journal journal {"hello, world", "just me, a class", 003}; //Works regardless of constructor definition.

    std::cout << a.name << " " << a.freq << std::endl;
    std::cout << journal.title << " " << journal.message << " " << journal.idNum << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

I found that it works with *structs and classes* regardless if they have a defined constructor.

Obviously default constructors are at work, but this confused me because of a few reasons:

- I've never seen this syntax before (not surprising, C++ is huge)
- It **actually works**
- Works regardless of a constructor being defined, so **may be** default behavior

My question is:

- Is there a name and specific purpose for this syntax which sets it apart from regular constructor behavior, and if so, why use it (or not)?

Comment: It's called [uniform initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uniform-initialization).

Comment: Little used is a big stretch. You might want to look for [uniform initialization](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#uniform-init). It has been a part of the language for half a decade now.

Comment: Thanks for the references!

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804312/initializer-list-syntax-in-member-initializer-list-c11 because that question is about writing a constructor, and this question is about using constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things have changed since the introduction of C++11 and you should probably read about [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

```
int x (0);  // Constructor initialization
int x {0};  // Uniform initialization
```

Before its introduction you had various initialization cases:

- objects by calling the usual () constructor (and watch out for [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) if no arguments are present)
- aggregate classes or arrays with {}
- default constructing with no braces

Now you can use uniform initialization in all of them.

It has to be noted that the two aren't really interchangeable since

```
std::vector<int> v (100); // 100 elements
std::vector<int> v {100}; // one element of value 100
```

and you have to pay attention to the fact that if the type has an [initializer list constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), it will take precedence in overload resolution.

That said, uniform initialization can be [quite handy](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/133690/22929) and safe (preventing narrowing conversions).

Answer (score 2):

That syntax is called "list initialization".  You can read more about it in Section 8.5.4 of [C++14](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf).

I would guess that this syntax mainly exists to be backwards compatible with C, which had syntax for initializing structs and arrays that looked very similar.

Comment: That syntax is **not** compatible with C (in C it would be `struct Foo obj = {i, j};`). Looking similar has never been a driving factor. The syntax exists to not collide with any other legal construct in C++. And it needed a new syntax, because it has stricter semantics (e.g. no narrowing conversions).